# Regex: Split String with repeated end pattern

Tags: regex, apex

Minor updates to the string as I did not phrase the problem statement clearly the first time round.

I have a string: `'( 5m 3s ) John: Hi <br> Hello <br>( 6m 2s ) Jane: Hello<br>'`

I am trying to match the string to extract each message as 1 line each.

```
1st group: ( 5m 3s ) John: Hi <br> Hello <br>
2nd group: ( 6m 2s ) Jane: Hello<br>
```

Can someone advice on the regex for this?
This is what I am trying to use currently and I am unable to tell the last break in the regex:

`(.*?).*?:.*?<br>`

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: Apex. Trying to use regex to come up with the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it, the actual delimiter pattern is "`<br>` followed by an opening round bracket".

The generic approach to match "something followed by ..." is to use positive lookahead construct (`(?=...)`):

```
\(.*?\).*?:.*?<br>(?=\(|$)
```

Here we restrict our `<br>` to match only if it is followed by `(` or end of string.

Please also note that parenthesis should be escaped; otherwise they define a capture group (or some other special regex construct depending on what goes after the opening one.)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YBay3w/1